# How to get the path of removable storage/sd card? Latest (/storage/???? ????) format as well

Tags: android, path, samsung-mobile, removable-storage

How to get the path of removable storage (removable SD Card) on Android 10, especially samsung phones.
As the location of the removable storage is now of the format /storage/???? ????
I found it hard to get the path as it changes with each phone.

I am posting the solution as well, it has worked well on Samsung and Mi phones.

Answer (score 1):

On every phone or emulator you get the path to app specific folder on removable micro sd card by using the second item returned by

```
getExternalFilesDirs()
```

The path is different for every micro sd card used.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to share a solution which took me days to find and hopefully shall help others as well. The removable sd card storage on latest android versions is like "/storage/???? ????", this location is quite hard to get. [I found the following code from here:](https://gist.github.com/PauloLuan/4bcecc086095bce28e22#gistcomment-2591001)
This code helps get the correct location even on Samsung phones. I have tried it on Samsung and Mi phones.

```
/**
```

- Get external sd card path using reflection
- @param mContext
- @param is_removable is external storage removable
- @return
  */

  ```
   private static String getExternalStoragePath(Context mContext, boolean is_removable) {

   StorageManager mStorageManager = (StorageManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
   Class<?> storageVolumeClazz = null;
   try {
       storageVolumeClazz = Class.forName("android.os.storage.StorageVolume");
       Method getVolumeList = mStorageManager.getClass().getMethod("getVolumeList");
       Method getPath = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("getPath");
       Method isRemovable = storageVolumeClazz.getMethod("isRemovable");
       Object result = getVolumeList.invoke(mStorageManager);
       final int length = Array.getLength(result);
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           Object storageVolumeElement = Array.get(result, i);
           String path = (String) getPath.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
           boolean removable = (Boolean) isRemovable.invoke(storageVolumeElement);
           if (is_removable == removable) {
               return path;
           }
       }
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return null;
  ```

  }